# View height error

Tags: statusbar, ios7

I'm playing with `iOS7` now, find that my view bounds became full screen
eg. before `320*460` now `320*480` with `20px` status bar over my view,
I know `iOS7` starts to support full screen layout, and has a

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

to set, but this line seems work only when the navigation bar is shown.

I can't upload screenshots. In `iOS6` view seems normal, and `320*460`, 
in `iOS7` it's `320*480`, status bar covers view contents.
If I use a navigation bar and set `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;`
view frame became `320*416`, leaves `20` for status bar and `44` for nav bar, but my app is a custom  top bar, not using navigation bar here.

If I change the frame of window, it moves down by `20 px`, but status bar seems clipped and a black `320*20` bar is shown,

Any method to make both `iOS6` and `iOS7` happy?

Answer (score 1):

From my observation you need to change the content inset of the tableview as you have the custom top bar which overlaps with the status bar. Please see the following code,

```
NSArray *vComp = [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
if ( [[vComp objectAtIndex:0] intValue] >= 7)//do this only for ios7+ {
        [self.tableview setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(64, 0, 0, 0)];
    }
```

where tableview refers your tableview which go beyond the status bar. And I have hardcoded the top position to 64 (status bar height(20)+navigation bar height(44)). Please update it according to ur design.

`setContentInset` is won't work with view. For view you need to updated the frame origin y position as like below,

```
if ( [[vComp objectAtIndex:0] intValue] >= 7)//do this only for ios7+ {
        CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
        viewFrame.origin.y = 64;//change this according to ur top bar height.
        self.view.frame = viewFrame;
}
```

Comment: voted mate, you seem like an expert, will you pls check this question of mine and give me some explanations? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609048/ios-fmdb-memory-leaks

Comment: This is not working. I am getting error `No visible @interface for 'UIView' declares the selector 'setContentInset:'`